# When will a CheckBox onChanged callback be called with a null value?

Tags: flutter, dart

The CheckBox 'onChanged' callback has a function signature type of 'ValueChanged<bool?>?'.

From reading [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox/onChanged.html), it is not made clear when the callback will be called with a value of null. A Checkbox is only ever in the state of checked or unchecked, so it seems like the value would always be either true or false, and not null.

Answer (score 0):

> A Checkbox is only ever in the state of checked or unchecked, so it seems like the value would always be either true or false, and not null.

Not true. I'm not sure what the original question was, but check [this property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox/tristate.html) on the documentation and you'll find out having `null` as a possible state might have sense in some applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is poor design on the flutter teams part.

Comment: I'm not sure about poor design, it may have sense from a Material perspective. Anyways, if you solved your issue, consider accepting / upvoting the answer to it becomes useful for the future.

Comment: It just should be an enum and not a null value.